# Dynamic dependent drop down selection in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am working on dynamic dependent drop down selection in CodeIgniter but unable to achieve the required output :( I Have tried all the solution on internet but unable to identify the mistake.. please help me regarding the issue.

Basically I have 2 tables in database. Equipment and Questions. 
Equipment table have 2 fields, Id and Name.
Questions table have 3 fields q_id, question, and eq_name.

I have 2 `<select>` fields. 
The first one is displaying equipment table values.
What I want is that, based on the equipment drop down options, the question `<select>` field should change as well.

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
public function getQuestion()
{
     $eq_name = $this->input->post('eq_name');

    $arrQuestion =$this->CEP_model->getQuestionQuery($eq_name);
    if(count($question)>0)
    {
        $ques_select_box='';
        $ques_select_box.='<option value=""> Select Question</option>';
        foreach($arrQuestion as $ques)
        {
            $arrQuestion[$ques->question] = $ques->question;
            $ques_select_box.='<option value="'.$ques->q_id.'">'.$ques->question.'</option>';
        }
        //print form_dropdown('question',$arrstates);
       echo json_encode($ques_select_box);

    }
}
```

Model:

```
public function getQuestionQuery($eq_name){$query = $this->db->query("SELECT question FROM questions WHERE eq_name = '{$eq_name}'");

  return $query->result();
 }
```

ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){$('#eq_name').on('change', function(){var eq_name = $(this).val();

 if(eq_name == '')
     {
         $('#question').prop('disabled', true);
     }
 else
    {
         $('#question').prop('disabled' , false);
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>CEP_controller/getQuestion ",
            type:"POST",
            data:{'eq_name' : eq_name},
            dataType:'json', 
            success:function(data){
               $('#question').html(data);

            },
            error: function(){
                 alert('Error Occured');
            }
        });
    }
     });});</script>
```

view:

```
<select class="form-control" name="eq_name"  id="eq_name">
   <option value="">--- Select Equipment ---</option><?php foreach($record as $row)
 { echo "<option>".$row['Name']."</option>";}?></select> <select class="form-control" name="question" id="question" disabled=""</select>
```

Comment: Please tell more about the problem. Do U have any errors?

Comment: you are very close, do these two changes, 1. remove `dataType:'json', `  2. replace `echo json_encode($ques_select_box);` with `$this->output->set_output($ques_select_box);` and small syntax error `>` missing `<select class="form-control" name="question" id="question" disabled=""></select>`

Comment: after i changed  dataType:'json'  to dataType:'html' it started working.
thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**json_encode()** encode **array** to **json sring** not **string** to **json**
Change in view

```
<select class="form-control" name="eq_name"  id="eq_name">
   <option value="">--- Select Equipment ---</option><?php foreach($record as $row)
 { echo "<option>".$row['Name']."</option>";}?></select> <select class="form-control" name="question" id="question" disabled=""></select>
```

And replace in **getQuestion()** of controllel
from

```
echo json_encode($ques_select_box);
```

to

```
echo $ques_select_box;
```

also remove  **dataType:'json',** from ajax

Comment: yeah it worked.. 
Thanks alot. main issue was this dataType:'json' once i removed it . it started working..:)

Comment: most welcome @RidaNasir, but it is bad practice to get all **HTML** data via **ajax**